# SQL / DB2 - retrieve value and update/increment simultaniously

Tags: sql, select, db2, sql-update, ibm-midrange

I'm connecting to a DB2 database and executing SQL statements.

One example of what is being done is:

```
select field from library/file
  [program code line finishes executing]
  [increment value by one]
update library/file set field = 'incremented value'
```

I have a need to immediately update the value while returning the value.  Rather than having to wait for the script to complete, and then run a separate UPDATE statement.

The concept of what I would like to do is this:

```
select field from library/file; update library/file set field = (Current Value + 1); go;
```

Please note... this is not the common SQL database most would be familiar with, it is a DB2 database on an IBM i.

Thanks!

Comment: Clarification: DB2 *is* an SQL database.  It is just a different implementation of SQL than the one you are used to.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I've clarified that it is not a 'normal sql database' :)

Comment: Are you _using_ the value of the field in your program?  If so, you may be better off using a stored procedure (with isolation level for the transaction) for this.  If not, just do a regular `UPDATE` statement.  Also, I'm assuming that you're somehow ensuring a unique row is selected/updated, or there could be interesting fallout.  Why are you incrementing the value this way, though?  What is it you're actually doing?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yes, I use the returned value in my program, increment that number by 1, and update the record with the incremented value.  There is only 1 column and 1 row in this table.  It's sole purpose is to provide a "next available number" sort of feature for a single application.  Having a SP created is an alternative, but would require a DB2 / RPG developer, I'd rather find an isolated solution I could implement myself.

Comment: ... Really, this is a terrible idea.  You should be using something called a [SEQUENCE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzsequences.htm), which basically does this automatically.  Especially because, if you have a concurrent environment, you need to lock access to the table (or you get duplicate values) - this means that insertion using this value would be serial, negating some of the advantage of a concurrent environment.  If you're able to create a table without a DBA... you should at least run your idea past them.

Comment: Nice, that seems like it would be a solution to my problem.  If you post that as an answer with some detail i'll mark this as complete.

Comment: DB2 **is** a normal SQL database.

Comment: Stored procedures can be written in SQL, so an RPG programmer is not necessarily required.  But it's always good to check with your DBA. (I say this as one ;-)

Comment: Also see this question:  [Is it possible to generate a unique numeric value for each row in an iSeries table without looping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366838/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-unique-numeric-value-for-each-row-in-an-iseries-tab/9370796#9370796)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update library/file set field = field + 1;
select field from library/file; 
[program code line finishes executing]
[increment value by one]
```

This handles the problem of another app updating the number between the time you fetch it and the time you update it.  Update it and then use it.  If two apps try to update simultaneously, one will wait.

A SEQUENCE object is designed exactly for this purpose, but if you are forced to keep this 'next ID' file updated, this is how I'd do it.  Follow the link in the comment by @Clockwork-Muse for info on the SEQUENCE object, or try [this example from V5R4](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/sqlp/rbafysequence.htm).

Comment: Without commitment control, it is still *theoretically* possible for two different jobs to UPDATE almost simultaneously, then both SELECT the same value.  The odds of this are probably *very* near zero in most situations, but if the result could be messy in some applications.  You can prevent this with an RR or RS isolation-level, maintaining record locks until a COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using a DB2 [SEQUENCE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzsequences.htm) to manage the next available number, if this file is simply intended to have a single row storing your counter.  That is what a SEQUENCE is designed to do.

To set it up, use a [CREATE SEQUENCE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzcsequence.htm) statement.

To increment the value and retrieve, use a [SEQUENCE reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzseqref.htm) expression of the form `NEXT VALUE FOR sequence-name`.  To find out what the most recent value was, use the `PREVIOUS VALUE FOR sequence-name`.  These expressions can be used like a regular any column expression, such as in a SELECT or INSERT statement.

Suppose, for example you want to do this for invoice numbers (and maybe your accounting department doesn't want their first invoice number to be 000001, so we will initialize it higher).

```
CREATE SEQUENCE InvoiceSeq
    as decimal (7,0)
    start with 27000; -- for example
```

You could get a number for a new invoice like this:

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR InvoiceSeq
    INTO :myvar
    FROM SYSIBM/SYSDUMMY1;
```

But what is this SYSIBM/SYSDUMMY1 table?  We're not really getting anything from table, so why are we pretending to do so?  The SELECT needs a FROM-table clause.  But since we don't need one, let's use a [VALUES INTO](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzvalinto.htm) statement.

```
VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR InvoiceSeq
    INTO :myvar;
```

So that has incremented the counter, and put the value into our variable.  You could use that value to INSERT into our InvoiceHeaders and InvoiceDetails tables.

**Or**, you could increment the counter as you write an InvoiceHeader, then use it again when writing the InvoiceDetails.

```
INSERT INTO InvoiceHeaders 
           (InvoiceNbr,                Customer, InvoiceDate)
    VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR InvoiceSeq, :custnbr, :invdate);

for each invoice detail
   INSERT INTO InvoiceDetails 
              (InvoiceNbr,                    InvoiceLine, Reason,   Fee)
       VALUES (PREVIOUS VALUE FOR InvoiceSeq, :line,      :itemtxt,  :amt);
```

The PREVIOUS VALUE is local to the particular job, so there should be no risk of another job getting the same number.

Comment: Note that I left the library (schema) name out of the examples.  This is to allow the system to use the library list to find things, somewhat like searching a path in Windows.  This allows the same program to run in different environments (such as testing vs production) without changing the code, simply by changing the library list.  Ask your DBA or other technical lead for guidance on the best method for your company.

Answer (score 0):

His request is like this:

```
UPDATE sometable
SET somecounter = somecounter + 10,
    :returnvar  = somecounter + 10;
```

Updates and retrieves at the same time.

This is possible in MSSQL, In fact I use it alot there,

but DB2 doesnt seem to have this feature.